# Zerah on bedsheets, permitted to learn Torah or daven in the presence of

Tags: halacha

If one's bedsheets are filthy with old zerah stains, and they are dry but they smell a little, would it be permitted to learn Torah silently, and/or daven or say brachos out loud in the presence of these sheets?  If not, are there any lenient opinions who say it is permitted?

Comment: According to SA OC 85, it would be forbidden, but the Taz does recommend considering ibid 82. I wonder if it falls under the same halacha of urine soaked in the ground and dried (2), but given that it still smells, it might be considered a _reiach ra she'yesh lo ikar_ (and it might be possible to engage in holy matters if it is covered).

Comment: @RabbiKaii which Taz are you referring to.

Comment: If it is so disgusting that it would intrude on a normal person's mind, then it would be forbidden. Otherwise it is fine.

Comment: @ClintEastwood is that simply your opinion or do you have a source for that